# Problema métodos switch case

Tags: java, array, método

Hola mi problema es el siguiente. Tengo distintos métodos y he creado un switch case para que el usuario por el método de entrada pueda decidir que opción tomar.

Los métodos son de arrays por lo tanto en el case no sé que variable enviar para que el programa utilice el método. Es difícil de explicar a ver si podéis entenderme. Dejo el código y veréis que en los `();break;` los tengo vacíos porque no sé que poner.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class mistermind {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
    int op=0;
    do {
        System.out.println("Decide una opción a hacer :");
        System.out.println("1-Introducir la combinación de numeros : \n2-Mostrar tabla indicada : \n3-Comprobar mi secuencia : \n4-Comparación final : \n5-Salir");
        switch(op){

        case 1:crearTabla();break;
        case 2:mostrarTablaUsuario();break;
        case 3:comprobarRepetido();break;
        case 4:resuelto();break;
        }

        }while(op!=1||op!=2|op!=3|op!=4);

    }
//En el hipotetico caso de que se quiera ver la respuesta mas adelante porque el jugador se ha rendido.
public static void mostrarRespuesta(int[]respuesta) {
    int matrizRespuesta[]=crearTabla();
        for(int i=0;i<matrizRespuesta.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(matrizRespuesta[i]);
        }

}
//Este muestra al usuario su propia combinación de numeros
public static void mostrarTablaUsuario (int[] mostrada) {
    int matrizPedida[]=pedirTabla();
    for(int i=0;i<matrizPedida.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(matrizPedida[i]);
    }
}
//Este crea una combinación para que el usuario la tenga que acertar
public static int[] crearTabla() {
        int matrizDefecto[] = new int [5];
        for(int i = 0; i < matrizDefecto.length; i++) {
            matrizDefecto[i]=(int)(Math.random()*9+1);

        }
        return matrizDefecto;
    }
//Pide al usuario una combinación de numeros
public static int[] pedirTabla() {
    Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
    int matrizJugador[]=new int [5];
    for(int i=0;i<matrizJugador.length;i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduce un numero del 1-6:");
        int num=entrada.nextInt();
        if(num>6|num<1) {
            System.out.println("El numero insertado tiene que estar entre el numero 1 y 9");
        }else {

            matrizJugador[i]=num;   
        }

    }
    return matrizJugador;
}
//Compara la matriz del usuario con los de la otra matriz original
public static void compropbarRepetido(int[]matrizDefecto,int[]matrizUsuario) {
 boolean incorrecto=false;
    for(int i=0;i<matrizDefecto.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<matrizUsuario.length;j++) {
            if(i==j&&matrizDefecto[i]==matrizUsuario[j]){
                    System.out.println("El numero "+matrizUsuario[j]+" existe y esta en su sitio");
                incorrecto=true;
            }
            if(i!=j&&matrizDefecto[i]==matrizUsuario[j]) {
                System.out.println("El numero "+matrizUsuario[j]+" esta, pero no en su sitio");
                incorrecto=true;
            }   
        }
    }
    if(incorrecto==false) {
        System.out.println("Ninguno de estos numeros se encuentra en la cadena");
    }
}
//Muestra si esta correcto el array o no
public static void resuelto(int[]matrizDefecto,int[]matrizUsuario){
    int matrizRespuesta[]=crearTabla();
    int matrizDelUsuario[]=pedirTabla();
    if(Arrays.equals(matrizRespuesta,matrizDelUsuario)) {
        System.out.println("Lo has hecho genial!! Las dos cadenas son identicas");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Mala suerte todavía no son identicas las cadenas, intentalo de nuevo ");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: No le pides al usuario ningún dato... debes asignar a op = entrada.nextInt(); Por defecto op, la condición que se evalua en el switch es 0 y por lo tanto no entra en ninguno de los case.

Comment: Es verdad que se le ha olvidado poner eso, pero el problema que tiene es que dentro de los case no sabe que datos mandar a los métodos. Supongo que esas variables serán variables con las que añade y juega él.

Comment: Sí que la he hecho yo @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia lo que pasa que como ya me marca mal lo de los switch no le he dado a ejecutar y no me he podido dar cuenta que me faltaba pedir al usuario que introduzca por entrada la variable op. Pero sí el problema básico es el que tu dices, lo de los métdos.

Comment: El problema lo tienes que cuando creas las variables las tienes como variables de los métodos y necesitas que sean globales, es decir declararlas fuera de las funciones. Y mandar estas en los métodos.

Comment: En este código solo hay variables locales ... ¿Nos perdemos de algo?

Comment: Sí, son variables locales. Me he equivocado, me refería a variables globales.Lo que no puedo hacer según el profesor es poner todo como variables globales, tendría que ser todo variables locales en los métodos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según lo que entiendo yo primero deberías poner en tu main dos variables locales:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] matrizUsuario = null; //todavia no se crea es necesario que el usario la
                              //ingrese aunque se podria pedir que el usario la 
  int[] matrizDefecto = crearTabla();//ya se crea porque es lo que se quiere
                                     // adivinar (se podría poner en el case
                                     // pero se le da la opcion al usuario de  
                                     //volver a generar la matriz)

  ...
```

y después usarlas en el switch:

```
...
System.out.println("Decide una opción a hacer :");
        System.out.println("1-Introducir la combinación de numeros : \n2-Mostrar tabla indicada : \n3-Comprobar mi secuencia : \n4-Comparación final : \n5-Salir");
        switch(op){
        case 1:
          tablaUsuario = pedirTabla();
          break;
        case 2:
          if(matrizUsuario == null){
             System.out.println("la matriz del usuario todavia no se ingreso")
          }else{
            mostrarTablaUsuario(matrizUsuario);
          }
          break;
        case 3:
          comprobarRepetido(matrizDefecto,matrizUsuario);
          break;
        case 4:
          resuelto(matrizDefecto,matrizUsuario);
          break;
        }
...
```

Comment: Perfecta explicación, es lo que estaba buscando

Answer (score -1):

La variable `op` siempre sera igual 0 ya que no estas leyendo la entrada del usuario.

Intenta utilizando [`Scanner#nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) que lee la entrada del usuario como un `int`:

```
    int op=0;
    do {
        System.out.println("Decide una opción a hacer :");
        System.out.println("1-Introducir la combinación de numeros : \n2-Mostrar tabla indicada : \n3-Comprobar mi secuencia : \n4-Comparación final : \n5-Salir");
       op = scanner.nextInt();

        switch(op){

        case 1:crearTabla();break;
        case 2:mostrarTablaUsuario();break;
        case 3:comprobarRepetido();break;
        case 4:resuelto();break;
        }

        }while(op!=1||op!=2|op!=3|op!=4);

//...
```

Comment: sí, eso me lo he olvidado pero no es el problema que tengo básicamente.